# how do I open different XMLs for various listview items?

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have generated a list using array adapters and listview. Now i want a  XML layout to open up each time i click on a list item. The layout format of all XMLs should be same,but the data in each XML should be different(for different list items).
How do i go about it?
**Here is the code**

```
public class handgunsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_handguns);
    ArrayList<String> hg=new ArrayList<String>();
    hg.add("M1911");
    hg.add("Desert Eagle .50");
    hg.add("Glock 17");
    hg.add("Sig P226");
    hg.add("Browning High-Power");

    ArrayAdapter<String> item=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,hg);
    final ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.root);
    list.setAdapter(item);
```

Comment: You mean you want to open an Activity or a Fragment when an item has been clicked?

Comment: Better to open a fragment I guess, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Add item click listener to your list, then get the selected item and pass it where ever you want to

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        // Here is the data, pass it any where
        String item = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }
});
```